# IOUSBInterfaceOpen fails, but I can get it to work by unmounting the camera... What's going on?

Tags: macos, usb, driver, iokit

I'm trying to write a Pentax camera USB driver for MacOs without much experience. I have been able to communicate with the camera using the example code in "Working with USB Device Interfaces" but only if I use asynchronous notifications and if I eject and reconnect the camera. It seems to work if during debug, the code captures the camera before it's mounted. I want to do it without notifications and a CFRunloop so I'm now trying to use IOServiceGetMatchingServices(). I can get the device, configure, do a DeviceRequest and even create a device interface, get it's class but USBInterfaceOpen fails. I think I need to setup a pipe to one of the endpoints so that DeviceRequest works for more than just getting status but I can't get past opening the interface. thanks

EDIT:

So it looks to me that the only interface is IOUSBHostInterface@0 and this is for mass storage access, correct? So I guess trying to send commands with DeviceRequest - to the control interface I presume - is the only option but that fails with error code e000404f. I believe I can formulate the command correctly as I can see the bytes in Wireshark but the whole packet is not the same as what I see on a PC USB. Maybe I still haven't got the correct command bytes?

```
+-o K-5 II@14200000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBDevice, id 0x100002645, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2976 ms), retai$
  | {
  |   "sessionID" = 116428207269670
  |   "USBSpeed" = 3
  |   "IOServiceLegacyMatchingRegistryID" = 4294977095
  |   "idProduct" = 328
  |   "bDeviceClass" = 0
  |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"PowerOverrideOn"=Yes,"CapabilityFlags"=32768,"MaxPowerState"=2,"DevicePowerState"=2,"ChildrenPowerState"=2,"Driver$
  |   "bcdDevice" = 263
  |   "USB Product Name" = "K-5 II"
  |   "AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID" = 4294977095
  |   "locationID" = 337641472
  |   "kUSBSerialNumberString" = "4585468"
  |   "bDeviceSubClass" = 0
  |   "kUSBCurrentConfiguration" = 1
  |   "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"9dc7b780-9ec0-11d4-a54f-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
  |   "bDeviceProtocol" = 0
  |   "USBPortType" = 0
  |   "USB Vendor Name" = "PENTAX"
  |   "idVendor" = 9723
  |   "USB Serial Number" = "4585468"
  |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
  |   "kUSBVendorString" = "PENTAX"
  |   "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBDevice"
  | }
  | 
  +-o AppleUSBHostLegacyClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHostLegacyClient, id 0x100002648, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0$
  |   {
  |     "IOPowerManagement" = {"DevicePowerState"=0,"CurrentPowerState"=1,"CapabilityFlags"=65536,"MaxPowerState"=2,"DriverPowerState"=1}
  |   }
  |   
  +-o AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice, id 0x100002650, !registered, !matched, active, $
  |   {
  |     "IOProbeScore" = 50000
  |     "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice"
  |     "IOProviderClass" = "IOUSBHostDevice"
  |     "IOClass" = "AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice"
  |     "bDeviceSubClass" = 0
  |     "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
  |     "kUSBPreferredConfiguration" = 1
  |     "bDeviceClass" = 0
  |   }
  |   
  +-o IOUSBHostInterface@0  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBInterface, id 0x100002652, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1112 $
    | {
    |   "USBPortType" = 0
    |   "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"2d9786c6-9ef3-11d4-ad51-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
    |   "bcdDevice" = 263
    |   "USBSpeed" = 3
    |   "idProduct" = 328
    |   "bConfigurationValue" = 1
    |   "bInterfaceSubClass" = 6
    |   "locationID" = 337641472
    |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
    |   "IOServiceLegacyMatchingRegistryID" = 4294977107
    |   "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBInterface"
    |   "AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID" = 4294977107
    |   "idVendor" = 9723
    |   "bInterfaceProtocol" = 80
    |   "bAlternateSetting" = 0
    |   "bInterfaceNumber" = 0
    |   "bInterfaceClass" = 8
    | }
    | 
    +-o IOUSBMassStorageInterfaceNub  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBMassStorageInterfaceNub, id 0x100002654, registered, matched, active$
      | {
      |   "IOClass" = "IOUSBMassStorageInterfaceNub"
      |   "idProduct" = 328
      |   "bInterfaceProtocol" = 80
      |   "USB Device Info" = {"bcdDevice"=263,"idProduct"=328,"kUSBVendorString"="PENTAX","bConfigurationValue"=1,"kUSBSerialNumberString"="458$
      |   "bcdDevice" = 263
      |   "IOProviderClass" = "IOUSBHostInterface"
      |   "Physical Interconnect Location" = "External"
      |   "USB Product Name" = "K-5 II"
      |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"DevicePowerState"=1,"CurrentPowerState"=1,"CapabilityFlags"=32768,"MaxPowerState"=1,"DriverPowerState"=1}
      |   "IOProbeScore" = 50000
      |   "locationID" = 337641472
      |   "kUSBSerialNumberString" = "4585468"
      |   "bInterfaceSubClass" = 6
      |   "bInterfaceClass" = 8
      |   "Physical Interconnect" = "USB"
      |   "bConfigurationValue" = 1
      |   "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
      |   "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver"
      |   "bInterfaceNumber" = 0
      |   "idVendor" = 9723
      |   "USB Mass Storage Trace ID" = 2736782607644622848
      |   "kUSBVendorString" = "PENTAX"
      | }
      | 
      +-o IOUSBMassStorageDriverNub  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBMassStorageDriverNub, id 0x100002656, registered, matched, active, bu$
        | {
        |   "IOClass" = "IOUSBMassStorageDriverNub"
        |   "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver"
        |   "IOProviderClass" = "IOUSBMassStorageInterfaceNub"
        |   "USB Mass Storage Trace ID" = 2736782607644622848
        |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"ChildrenPowerState"=1,"DevicePowerState"=1,"CurrentPowerState"=1,"CapabilityFlags"=32768,"MaxPowerState"=1,"$
        |   "idProduct" = 328
        |   "IOProbeScore" = 0
        |   "bConfigurationValue" = 1
        |   "bInterfaceSubClass" = 6
        |   "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
        |   "kUSBVendorString" = "PENTAX"
        |   "USB Product Name" = "K-5 II"
        |   "USB Device Info" = {"bcdDevice"=263,"idProduct"=328,"kUSBVendorString"="PENTAX","bConfigurationValue"=1,"kUSBSerialNumberString"="4$
        |   "Physical Interconnect" = "USB"
        |   "idVendor" = 9723
        |   "bInterfaceProtocol" = 80
        |   "Physical Interconnect Location" = "External"
        |   "bInterfaceNumber" = 0
        |   "bInterfaceClass" = 8
        | }
        | 
        +-o IOUSBMassStorageDriver  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOSCSIProtocolInterface:IOSCSIProtocolServices:IOUSBMassStorageDriver, id 0$
          | {
          |   "IOClass" = "IOUSBMassStorageDriver"
          |   "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver"
          |   "IOProviderClass" = "IOUSBMassStorageDriverNub"
          |   "Write Time Out Duration" = 30000
          |   "USB Mass Storage Trace ID" = 2736782607644622848
          |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"ChildrenPowerState"=1,"DevicePowerState"=1,"CurrentPowerState"=1,"CapabilityFlags"=32768,"MaxPowerState"=1$
          |   "Read Time Out Duration" = 30000
          |   "IOProbeScore" = 0
          |   "IOUnit" = 16
          |   "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
          |   "Retry Count" = 20
          |   "Protocol Characteristics" = {"Physical Interconnect"="USB","Read Time Out Duration"=30000,"Physical Interconnect Location"="Exter$
          |   "bInterfaceProtocol" = 80
          |   "Physical Interconnect Location" = "External"
          |   "No INQUIRY VPD Pages" = Yes
          | }
          | 
          +-o IOSCSILogicalUnitNub@0  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOSCSIProtocolInterface:IOSCSIProtocolServices:IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceNub:$
            | {
            |   "TPGS Information" = 0
            |   "Peripheral Device Type" = 0
            |   "Vendor Identification" = "PENTAX"
            |   "SCSI Logical Unit Number" = 0
            |   "IOMatchCategory" = "SCSITaskUserClientIniter"
            |   "Product Identification" = "DSC_K-5_II"
            |   "Protocol Characteristics" = {"Physical Interconnect"="USB","Read Time Out Duration"=30000,"SCSI Logical Unit Number"=0,"Physica$
            |   "IOUnitLUN" = 0
            |   "Product Revision Level" = "1.07"
            | }
            | 
            +-o IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOSCSIProtocolInterface:IOSCSIPrimaryCommandsDevice:IOSCSIBlockCo$
              | {
              |   "IOClass" = "IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00"
              |   "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice"
              |   "IOProviderClass" = "IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceNub"
              |   "IOMaximumBlockCountRead" = 256
              |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"CapabilityFlags"=49216,"MaxPowerState"=4,"ActivityTickles"=58,"IdleTimerPeriod"=200000,"DevicePowerSta$
              |   "IOMaximumBlockCountWrite" = 256
              |   "IOProbeScore" = 5000
              |   "Peripheral Device Type" = 0
              |   "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
              |   "IOMaximumByteCountWrite" = 131072
              |   "WriteCacheState" = No
              |   "IOMaximumByteCountRead" = 131072
              | }
              | 
              +-o IOBlockStorageServices  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOBlockStorageDevice:IOBlockStorageServices, id 0x100002660, register$
                | {
                |   "IOMinimumSegmentAlignmentByteCount" = 4
                |   "device-type" = "Generic"
                |   "Device Characteristics" = {"Vendor Name"="PENTAX","Product Name"="DSC_K-5_II","Product Revision Level"="1.07"}
                |   "Protocol Characteristics" = {"Physical Interconnect"="USB","Read Time Out Duration"=30000,"SCSI Logical Unit Number"=0,"Phy$
                | }
                | 
                +-o IOBlockStorageDriver  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOStorage:IOBlockStorageDriver, id 0x100002661, registered, matched, $
                  | {
                  |   "IOPropertyMatch" = {"device-type"="Generic"}
                  |   "IOProbeScore" = 0
                  |   "IOProviderClass" = "IOBlockStorageDevice"
                  |   "IOClass" = "IOBlockStorageDriver"
                  |   "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily"
                  |   "Statistics" = {"Operations (Write)"=6,"Latency Time (Write)"=0,"Bytes (Read)"=2269184,"Errors (Write)"=0,"Total Time (Rea$
                  |   "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
                  |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
                  | }
                  | 
                  +-o PENTAX DSC_K-5_II Media  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOStorage:IOMedia, id 0x100002664, registered, matched, active, $
                    | {
                    |   "Removable" = Yes
                    |   "Content" = "FDisk_partition_scheme"
                    |   "Whole" = Yes
                    |   "Leaf" = No
                    |   "BSD Name" = "disk2"
                    |   "Ejectable" = Yes
                    |   "Preferred Block Size" = 512
                    |   "IOMediaIcon" = {"IOBundleResourceFile"="Removable.icns","CFBundleIdentifier"="com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily"}
                    |   "BSD Minor" = 8
                    |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
                    |   "Writable" = Yes
                    |   "BSD Major" = 1
                    |   "Size" = 16147022336
                    |   "IOBusyInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
                    |   "Open" = Yes
                    |   "Content Hint" = ""
                    |   "BSD Unit" = 2
                    | }
                    | 
                    +-o IOMediaBSDClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOMediaBSDClient, id 0x100002665, registered, matched, active, busy 0$
                    |   {
                    |     "IOClass" = "IOMediaBSDClient"
                    |     "IOMatchCategory" = "IOMediaBSDClient"
                    |     "IOProbeScore" = 30000
                    |     "IOProviderClass" = "IOMedia"
                    |     "IOResourceMatch" = "IOBSD"
                    |     "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily"
                    |   }
                    |   
                    +-o IOFDiskPartitionScheme  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOStorage:IOPartitionScheme:IOFDiskPartitionScheme, id 0x100002$
                      | {
                      |   "IOPropertyMatch" = {"Whole"=Yes}
                      |   "IOProbeScore" = 3000
                      |   "IOMatchCategory" = "IOStorage"
                      |   "IOClass" = "IOFDiskPartitionScheme"
                      |   "IOProviderClass" = "IOMedia"
                      |   "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily"
                      |   "Content Mask" = "FDisk_partition_scheme"
                      |   "Content Table" = {"0xA9"="NetBSD","0x82"="Linux_Swap","0x01"="DOS_FAT_12","0xA7"="Apple_Rhapsody_UFS","0x0B"="DOS_FAT$
                      | }
                      | 
                      +-o Untitled 1@1  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOStorage:IOMedia, id 0x10000266b, registered, matched, active, busy 0 $
                        | {
                        |   "Removable" = Yes
                        |   "Content" = "DOS_FAT_32"
                        |   "Whole" = No
                        |   "Leaf" = Yes
                        |   "BSD Name" = "disk2s1"
                        |   "Ejectable" = Yes
                        |   "Preferred Block Size" = 512
                        |   "Base" = 4194304
                        |   "BSD Minor" = 9
                        |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
                        |   "Writable" = Yes
                        |   "Partition ID" = 1
                        |   "BSD Major" = 1
                        |   "Size" = 16142827520
                        |   "IOBusyInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
                        |   "Open" = Yes
                        |   "Content Hint" = "DOS_FAT_32"
                        |   "BSD Unit" = 2
                        | }
                        | 
                        +-o IOMediaBSDClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOMediaBSDClient, id 0x10000266c, registered, matched, active, bu$
                            {
                              "IOClass" = "IOMediaBSDClient"
                              "IOMatchCategory" = "IOMediaBSDClient"
                              "IOProbeScore" = 30000
                              "IOProviderClass" = "IOMedia"
                              "IOResourceMatch" = "IOBSD"
                              "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily"
                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the reason for my problems. I found out that indeed, in order to command the camera I need to send Bulk commands because the camera control is tunnelled though the bulk control. You issue a bulk command with an embedded custom command that the camera will respond to.

I've seen the bulk command on the PC by using Wireshark while talking to the camera with PK_Tether. (Another interesting fact is that pk_tether could not access the bulk storage unless I had an SD card int the cameras card slot.)

So now I have to find out how to issue bulk commands so I'll ask that question on a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

First, what's the error code returned? I'm guessing `kIOReturnExclusiveAccess` but it'd be good to know for sure.

Second, does the device report as a composite device? In that case, you shouldn't be trying to open the USB *device* but the USB *interface* that's of interest to you.

If that still fails, or if it's not a composite device, this problem typically means that another driver has claimed the device already. Check with IORegistryExplorer.app or the `ioreg` command line tool to find out what process or kernel driver has the device open.

Comment: Yes, you are right, when I turn on the camera, it gets mounted and I run the code and try to do:
 kr = (*interface)->USBInterfaceOpen(interface);

the error code is: 0x2c5
 #define kIOReturnExclusiveAccess iokit_common_err(0x2c5) // exclusive access and
                                                         //   device already open 

If I eject the camera and run the code, I get the same error.

So if I skip the: kr = (*dev)->USBDeviceOpen(dev); part of the code for both of the above conditions, I get the same error.

Comment: I believe it is a “composite” as you say because it mounts as a mass storage device but I’m pretty sure I need to open another interface to get access to a control endpoint of the device, to trigger the shutter, for example. But this is where I’m having the problem, can’t open the interface.

Looking at the ioregistry, I see that there is only interface 0 which seems to be used for the mass storage access. Then there is a higher level control point I guess, that I have been able to query but try to send commands and they fail too. Ejecting the camera does not clear the registry.

Comment: Using Wireshark on a pc, I see there are 8-16 more bytes being sent when I try a "DeviceRequest". I'm guessing that's because the command is going through an interface to an endpoint that I haven't been able to open.

Comment: I see IORegistryExplorer says that the mass storage driver is connected to the device. How do I remove that since eject does not do it?

Comment: In linux, there is a rules file to prevent the camera being mounted as a disk. Do I need to do that? How?

Comment: Can you please run `ioreg -lirc IOUSBHostDevice` and update your question with the entire subtree for the device you're trying to access? I have my doubts that you should be sending camera commands to a mass storage interface. If the camera control interface does not appear, perhaps it is a question of enabling an alternate configuration on the composite device?

Comment: Thanks @pmdj . I'll do that.